# Tailwind: how to fit image inside navbar parent div

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a simple header in which I want to insert a profile image. However profile image doesn't fit the header and I'm not sure how to approach it in a responsive manner. I don't want to hardcore the width/height of the image in any manner, but rather I want it to always fit the height of the header, with some paddings.

My code is:

```
    <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-start
          m-3 p-2 pl-6  ">
      <span class="title-text light-text text-xl">Some Title</span>
      <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>
      <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>
      <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>
      <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>

      <div class="rounded">
        <img class= "relative rounded-full border
              border-gray-100 shadow-sm
         max-w-max   h-full " src="../../assets/dog.jpeg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Without image it looks like this:

[image]

But with image it looks like this:

[image]

However I want it to look:

[image]

How do I achieve it, using Tailwind?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late but I've just been working on this and the solution for me was to set:

- image height `className=h-8` to control sizing
- container margins to control positioning `className=ml-auto`.
  I'm using tailwind in react, so full code is:

```
import GitHubLogo from '../media/GitHubLogo.svg';

const tools = [
  'Transcribe',
  'Reverse complement',
  'Translate',
  'Primer check',
  'Primer design',
];

export const Navbar = () => (
    <nav className="flex w-11/12 p-2 mx-auto rounded bg-coral-std">
      <h1 className="text-4xl btn"> welcome</h1>
      {tools.map((tool) => (
        <a
          href={`/#${tool}`}
          className="inline-flex px-6 py-2 rounded hover:bg-slate-200/20"
          key={tool}
        >
          {tool}
        </a>
      ))}

<a href="https://github.com/ccozens/mol-bio-tools/" target='_' className="ml-auto">
      <img
      src={GitHubLogo}
      alt="GitHub logo"
      className="h-8 pr-1 mx-auto"
      >
      </img>
      Source code</a>
        </nav>
);
```

Note the `mx-auto` flag in the image class centres the image over the image label; this isn't impacting the right positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit):cover, note that you will have to set the with and the height of the img to 100%.

```
.rounded{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.rounded img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

here is the link for [tailwind-css](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit) meaning you can use this class `object-cover` only

```
  <div class="rounded">
    <img class= "object-cover relative rounded-full border
          border-gray-100 shadow-sm
     max-w-max   h-full " src="../../assets/dog.jpeg" />
  </div>
```

Comment: What about `img class="object-scale-down"` or even  `img class="object-contain"` ? can you provide a link to your page? probabily you need to set a `height` to your img parent `<div class="rounded"> `.

Answer (score 0):

Give the fixed height to the nav and the image container,

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-start px-4 bg-gray-800 text-white h-20">
  <span class="title-text light-text text-xl">Some Title</span>
  <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>
  <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>
  <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>
  <span class="pl-10">Some link</span>

  <div class="h-16 ml-auto">
    <img class= "rounded-full border border-gray-100 shadow-sm h-full" src="../../assets/dog.jpeg" />
  </div>
</div>
```